# Maven repository jars comes with "xxx-sources.jar"

Tags: java

My jars in maven repository are appended with "-sources" like for example: junit-4.12-sources.jar. Please let me know what I can do to avoid this.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I was able to find the solution for this problem. I checked "Force Update of snapshots/Releases" an dupdated the project. In eclipse, you can do this by: Right click on the project --> Maven --> Update Project… --> Select the project that you want to update --> Check “Force Update of snapshots/Releases” and all the other 3 options are check by default --> OK. Build your project again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. I was able to find the solution for this problem. I checked "Force Update of snapshots/Releases" an dupdated the project. In eclipse, you can do this by: Right click on the project --> Maven --> Update Project… --> Select the project that you want to update --> Check “Force Update of snapshots/Releases” and all the other 3 options are check by default --> OK. Build your project again.

Answer (score 2):

Theese are source files for libraries you are using. You can disable it by setting downloadSources to FALSE.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>false</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```